# How do i make a batch file launch a exe file

Tags: batch-file, exe, executable, launcher

I need to make a launcher that executes a file and then exits when i use this i get a message saying Do you wish to terminate batch job y/n. or something like that. does anyone know a way to make it close after it has executed the program. I am currently using the script below.

```
 @echo off
 %~dp0
 Program.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The %~dp0 is causing the batch file to run itself again. I think you want `pushd %~dp0` to change the directory to the location of the batch file. I'd remove the . from the end of program.exe too.

Comment: Or possibly `CD /D %~dp0`. If you do use `pushd`, you might want to use `popd` at the end of the batch file. It would depend on whether this is normally invoked at a command prompt, or from a shortcut.